# External resources not reaching inside of function scope

Tags: javascript, function, scope

I'm trying to make an inventory picker for my trading website, but I'm having some trouble calling external resources.

When originally calling the external function, all goes correctly, but whenever I try to call the external function INSIDE of a function in the html, it errors, saying

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).imagepicker is not a function
```

This is my relevant code.

```
<script src="~/Scripts/image-picker.js"></script>


<script>
    var name = "HomeguardDev";
    var inventory = [];
    var selectedItems = [];
    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        type: 'GET',
        url: "/Home/getInventory/?username=" + name + "&page=1",
        success: function (data) {
            var parsed = JSON.parse(data);
            for (var i = 0; i < parsed.length; i++) {
                var text = parsed[i].Name;
                inventory[i] = parsed[i];
                if (parsed[i].SerialNumber !== "---") {
                    text = text + " [#" + parsed[i].SerialNumber + " / " + parsed[i].SerialNumberTotal + "]";
                }
                $("#sendingItems").append('<option data-img-label="<small>' + text + '</small>" data-img-src="' + parsed[i].ImageLink + '" value="' + i + '">' + text + '</option>');
            }
        }
    });
    $("#sendingItems").imagepicker({
        show_label: true
    });
    function addItem() {
        if (selectedItems.length < 4) {
            var obj = (inventory[$("#sendingItems").val()]);
            if (!containsObject(obj, selectedItems)) {
                $('#sendingItems option[value="' + ($("#sendingItems").val()) + '"]').remove();
                selectedItems.push(obj);
                $("#sendingItems").imagepicker({
                    show_label: true
                });
            }
        }
    }
</script>
<p><a><input type="button" id="addItemButton" onclick="addItem()" value="Add item" /></a></p>
<p><a><input type="button" id="sendTradeButton" onclick="sendTrade()" value="Send Trade" /></a></p>
```

The error occurs inside of the function addItem() when calling imagepicker, but in the main block it calls and functions correctly. What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: All of that should be wrapped in `$.ready`. Also are you sure the plugin isnt camel case or something like `.imagePicker()`? Also are you including jquery and image picker before the script tag with your code in it?

Comment: okay, I'll try $.ready, and I know it isn't camelCase, because it works on the first call, but not on the call inside of the function. I'm including both sources in the first line of the html.

Comment: @prodigitalson That broke it even worse unfortunately. Wrapping it in the ready function made it undefined again, but if I put it outside of the ready it calls correctly.